Form validation through two app script libraries
The problem is after clicking on the button. I'm getting

Uncaught ReferenceError: check is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

This is my scenario:
I have two standalone libraries. The first contains all the logic, forms, HTML, CSS, and functions.
In the second, I installed the first library and I call it with
function start() {return first.run();};

Users install the second library and use doGet to launch the webapp
function doGet() {return second.start();};

My code:
form.html
<body>
    <form id="loginForm">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
        <br>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="check()">
    </form>
    <script>
        function validate() {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(response){
                if(response) {
                    alert("Login success");
                } else {
                    alert("Login failed");
                }
            }).check(document.getElementById('username').value, document.getElementById('password').value);
        }
    </script>
</body>

//function
function check(username, password) {
  if (username === 'admin' && password === 'password') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

I expect all the logic to be handled by library 1, users install the second library in their project and publish the webapp. The role of the second library is to simulate a bridge. Trying with only one library I got the same error

You should focus on solving the problem of using only one library first.

The referred error is solved by making a change on the file form.html
From
<input type="button" value="Login" onclick="check()">

To
<input type="button" value="Login" onclick="validate()">

The above is because form.html calls a function named check when a button is clicked, but the JavaScript code doesn't have a function named this way. The only JavaScript function on the client side is called validate.
Reference

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication


Uncaught TypeError: google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(...).check is not a function
After all the necessary tests, I receive the same error. It seems that the only solution is to add validate() function in the webapp

See Call Library function from html with google.script.run

This solution didn't work. Maybe it's because I use two libraries

@hub2sell Create a new question including a [mcve], Code of both libraries, code of the main project, deployment settings and how are you testing the code : if you use a test deployment , creates a new version or a new deployment.
